# Uncaught Typeerror: b.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: 2013, spservices, sharepoint-on-prem

I'm using SPServices and cannot figure out why I keep getting this error thrown from the jQuery library that b.toLowercase is not a function.   Here are complete details of the error:

```
jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: b.toLowerCase is not a function
 at Function.ga.attr (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
 at attr (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5) 
at m.access (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4) 
at m.fn.init.attr (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5) at Element.<anonymous> (https://STandardization_copy(1).aspx:732:16) at Function.each (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2) at m.fn.init.each (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2) at Object.completefunc (https://STandardization_copy(1).aspx:731:46) at Object.complete (jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js:19) at j (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
ga.attr @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
attr    @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
m.access    @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
attr    @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
(anonymous) @   PMSTandardization_copy(1).aspx:732
each    @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
each    @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
completefunc    @   PMSTandardization_copy(1).aspx:731
complete    @   jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js:19
j   @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
fireWith    @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
x   @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
b   @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
send    @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
ajax    @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
ao.fn.SPServices    @   jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js:19
(anonymous) @   STandardization_copy(1).aspx:724
j   @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
fireWith    @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
ready   @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
J   @   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
```

Here is my code.  I'm using a CEWP that links to an html file containing all of the code:

```
$().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='docLink' /></ViewFields>",
            listName: "PM",
            debug: true,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
                                            if ($(this).attr("docLink" === 2)){
                                            setTimeout(function(){
                                            location.relod(true);
                                            },3000);
                                            }
                            });
              }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon further review, realized this was a syntax error.  Forgot to add a closing ) to attr.